# Can you start and stop boundschecker (DevPartner)?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, bounds-checker, devpartner

I'm trying to use boundschecker to analyze a rather complex program.  Running the program with boundschecker is almost too slow for it to be of any use since it takes me almost a day to run the program to the point in the code where I suspect the issue exists.  Can anyone give me some ideas for how to inspect only certain parts of my software using boundschecker (DevPartner) in Visual Studio 2005?

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I last used BoundsChecker a few years ago, and had the same problems. With large projects, it makes everything run so slowly that it is useless. We ended up ditching it.

But, we still needed some of it's functionality, but like you, not for the whole program. So we had to do it ourselves.

In our case, we mainly used it to try and track down memory leaks. If that's your objective as well, there are other options.

1. Visual Studio does a pretty good job of telling you about memory leaks when your program exits
2. It reports leaks in the order that they were created
3. It will tell you exactly where the leaked memory was created if your source files have this at the top

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#undef THIS_FILE
static char THIS_FILE[]=__FILE__;
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif
```

Those help a lot, but it's often not enough. Adding that snippet everywhere isn't always feasible. If you use factory classes, knowing where memory was allocated doesn't help at all. So when all else fails, we take advantage of #2.

Add something like the following:

```
#define LEAK(str) {char *s = (char*)malloc(100); strcpy(s, str);}
```

Then, pepper your code with "LEAK("leak1");" or whatever. Run the program, and exit it. Your new leaked strings will display in Visual Studio's leak dump surrounding the existing leaks. Keep adding/moving your LEAK statements and re-running the program to narrow your search until you've pinpointed the exact location. Then fix the leak, remove your debugging leaks, and you're all set!

Answer (score 0):

BoundsChecker tracks all memory allocations and releases in extreme detail.  It knows, for instance, that such and such a memory allocation was done from the C runtime heap, which in turn was taken from a Win32 heap, which in turn started life as memory allocated by VirtualAlloc.  If the application was instrumented (FinalCheck), it also has detailed information as to which pointers reference the memory.

This is one reason (of many) why the thing is slow.

If BC were to connect to an application late, it would have none of this data built up, and would have either (1) dig it all up at once, or (2) start guessing about things.  Neither solution is very practical.

Comment: That said, we -are- looking into what can be done with simply turning the API processing on and off at user request.  For API validation, this is not a problem.  For memory tracking, we run into the problems I described above.  If I can speed up basic memory tracking, we may be able to have a hybrid mode wherein memory tracking (but not allocation stack capture and similar things) occurs, but all else is disabled until the user says "Go", at which point full analysis starts.  Ideas continue to percolate in our collective heads...

Answer (score 0):

One way to lighten up BoundsChecker is by excluding from instrumentation all but the few modules you are interested in. I know thats not great because if you knew where the leak was you wouldn't need BoundsChecker. What I usually recommend is that you use BC's Active Check mode first with only Memory Tracking available. You miss the API Validations but you could always rerun that seperately. After you run Active Check and you get clues regarding which modules tend to be problematic, only then do you enable instrumentation for the module or modules of interest and their dependencies. We know Final Check is annoyingly slow but as Mistiano correctly states, with Final Check not only does BC keep a graph of all allocated blocks but also all pointers and contexts to them. Therein lies the magic in how Final Check can nail leaks and corruptions at the point of occurance, not just on application shutdown or fault. Shameless plug: I work on the DevPartner team. We are releasing DPS 10.5 on February 4, 2011 with x64 application support in BC. Unlike the relatively ancient and undersold BC64 for Itanium which only provided Active Check, DPS 10.5 provides full Final Check support for x64 applications, both for pure C++ and for native modules running in .NET processes. See microfocus.com under MF Developer for details.